# Cast value from NSCFConstantString to NSDictionary

Tags: swift, firebase, dictionary, firebase-realtime-database, observer-pattern

I want to observe my Firebase Database for changes and retrieve them in my app. Unfortunately, I am always getting this error

**Could not cast value of type '__NSCFConstantString' (0x10b197760) to 'NSDictionary' (0x10b198818)**

This is the code

```
func retrieveData (){

    let messageID = Database.database().reference().child("PatientID")

    messageID.observe(.childAdded) { (snapshot) in

        let snapshotvalue = snapshot.value as! Dictionary <String,String>

        let text = snapshotvalue ["MessageBody"]!
        let sender = snapshotvalue ["Sender"]!

        let dataEntry = DataLog()

        dataEntry.MessageBody = text
        dataEntry.Sender = sender

        self.itemArray.append(dataEntry)


        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }


}
```

Comment: `snapshot.value` is obviously a string, not a dictionary.

Comment: would you show me your solution in code?

Comment: Rather than to Dictionary cast `snapshot.value` to String. But then you will get new errors in the next two lines

Comment: `snapshot.value` is a `String`. Question is why? Is it normal? Could you print it?

Comment: `PatientID` sounds more like the name of a property than a structure, are you sure you're using the right key for `.child()`?

Comment: Yes I am sure, that I am using the right    .child()

Comment: Do you mind print `snapshop.value`?